# Angular2 form bidi-mapping and Typescript enum property as a number

Tags: forms, typescript, angular, bidirectional

Given the following template:

```
<select id="IdCtrl" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="obj.enumProperty">
  <option *ngFor="let p of EnumVals" [value]="p.value">{{p.name}}</option>
</select>
```

where

```
EnumVals: [{name: string, value: number}]
```

and `enumProperty` is some TypeScript `enum`.

Now, the bidirectional mapping is producing me the value as `string`, not as a `number`. Do I do something wrong or it's a correct behavior?

P.S. I could always cast it manually to `number`, but I would like to have it done behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is, that  value property **always has only string** inside. So, Angular can convert your 'number' from a model to a 'string' (just using toString() by default), but it is not allowed to parse it back. Unfortunately.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's not the *goal*. The goal is to have a type safe language, where strings are not type safe.

Comment: But why you are judging the language (framework is not a language)?
Anyway, you are using here 2 bidirectional bindings = one for obj.enumProperty for ngModel and another - EnumVals for ngFor.
Angular change detection system only monitor changes on elements, related to the current binding (p.value), and ngmodel only listens for a simple native `onchange` event from a `<select>` element, which always returns string and on this event there is no sanitizing..
Current case is quite tricky to implements automatically, but only one solution - to register a feature on official angular's github

Comment: Hmm.. I've got your question, I reproduced it by myself - this behavior is really exists, you are right.
I'm proposing to you a question - you are doing everything right, but it is a current behavior for current version of Angular 2, all that I can notice )
And only one way to achieve desired behavior - to register a feature (or a bug) at github or, what is better - to contribute it, open source in action )